# Why can't I use smoothing with the pencil tool?

Tags: adobe-flash

I can't use smoothing with the pencil tool. When I try to use it, it returns an error message stroke smoothness. Adobe flash CC.

Here is a screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The problem is I can't select smoothness..

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Sure i will add it within an hour..

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please visit [tour] to learn who and what we are, and also see [ask] and [answer] to understand how best to frame queries and what to expect of replies. FYI: when folks here refer to "screenshot" they mean screen capture from the OS of the device itself on which your software is running, and they expect it to include either the whole of the application at hand, or at least the area of concern which will help diagnose issues.

Comment: Please use the "print screen" for the screenshot...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe answering a bit late, but you need to change your pencil mode:

[image]

from freehand or straighten (where you can't edit the smoothing) to smoothing where you can edit the smoothing value. Hope this helps :)